# Administrator role not recognized if user logs in from another language

Tags: multilingual

We have a bi-lingual site in Mexico running civicrm on drupal and the default language is English. Some users with administrator roles get "access denied" messages when they log in from a Spanish language computer. Is there a way around this??

Comment: what url are they at when they get that msg, and what is the english language link for same page?